# Any way to automatically convert function calls to double colon (::) notation?

Tags: r, function, package, roxygen

I am creating an R package where I want to store several functions I wrote in the past. As I understand that I should use the double colon operator `package::function` whenever I call an external function, I am going through my code in RStudio to fix all function calls.

Is there a way to script/automatize this? It looks like something that should not be done manually, yet I couldn't find anywhere a way to do this.

PS: I am aware that I can also add `@importFrom package function` to the `NAMESPACE` both directly and through `#' @importFrom package function`, but that involves a lot of manual typing as well, plus a good deal of back and forth from the body of the function to the header.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you want is to find patterns and prefix them with something, where `gsub` is your friend.

**Consider the following as a sketch of an approach!**

You might have a named list with names and functions of the external packages like this.

```
funs_p1 <- c('exfun1a', 'exfun1b')
funs_p2 <- c('exfun2')
funs_p3 <- c('exfun3')
(fun_lst <- list(pac1=funs_p1, pac2=funs_p2, pac3=funs_p3))
# $pac1
# [1] "exfun1a" "exfun1b"
# 
# $pac2
# [1] "exfun2"
# 
# $pac3
# [1] "exfun3"
```

Then best cd in your working directory,

```
setwd('fundir')
```

and list the .R scripts using `list.files`.

```
rscripts <- list.files(pattern='.R$')
```

Then in a loop through the file names of your R scripts using `lapply`,

1. `readLines` into an object
2. `gsub` patterns with function names and prefix them with package names and the colons in a `for` loop
3. `writeLines` to the .R scripts (I prefixed them with `'changed_'` what should be easily removable but does not overwrite your original files, comment out the line if you are sure, otherwise it `return`s only the text to be written)

```
lapply(rscripts, \(x) {
  rl <- readLines(x)
  for (i in seq_along(fun_lst)) {
    rl <- gsub(sprintf('(%s)', paste(paste0(fun_lst[[i]], '\\('), collapse='|')), 
               sprintf('%s::\\1', names(fun_lst)[i]), rl)
  }
  # writeLines(rl, paste0('changed_', x)) |> invisible()
  return(rl)
})
# [[1]]
# [1] "myfun1a <- function() {"         
# [2] "  a <- pac1::exfun1a(some, args)"
# [3] "  mean(a)"                       
# [4] "}"                               
# [5] ""                                
# [6] "myfun1b <- function() {"          
# [7] "  a <- pac3::exfun3(some, args)" 
# [8] "  sum(a)"                        
# [9] "}"                               
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "myfun2 <- function() {"          
# [2] "  a <- pac1::exfun1b(some, args)"
# [3] "  mean(a)"                       
# [4] "}"                               
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "myfun3 <- function() {"         
# [2] "  a <- pac2::exfun2(some, args)"
# [3] "  sum(a)"                       
# [4] "}"
```

**Notice, that this is dangerous and might overwrite your work without undo!** Therefore, be sure to create a backup copy and practice with toy examples like this one.

**Caveats:** There are functions with the same name throughout the packages, e.g. `stats::filter` and `dplyr::filter`, you should exclude them to not produce a mess. Also, if objects have the same names or parts, they might get prefixed as well, I tried to approach that by adding opening the parenthesis to the patterns.

---

*Data:*

Store these lines in three separate .R scripts to reproduce:

```
# fun1.R:
myfun1a <- function() {
  a <- exfun1a(some, args)
  mean(a)
}

myfun1b <- function() {
  a <- exfun3(some, args)
  sum(a)
}


# fun2.R:
myfun2 <- function() {
  a <- exfun1b(some, args)
  mean(a)
}


# fun3.R:
myfun3 <- function() {
  a <- exfun2(some, args)
  sum(a)
}
```